# Compare Just Created ArrayList to the one before

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, compare

I am having trouble figuring out how to compare each individual value of the ArrayList. I do this by assigning an empty ArrayList before the ArrayList I am about fill in but for some reason it fills both at the same time when I run the method. Do any of you have an idea why? Note: this code is not doing comparison but I can't fill them right in the first place to attempt to do comparison.

```
List<Long> StationsArrayListG7 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Long> StationsArrayListG7a = new ArrayList<>();


public void GetApplicationSpecificUserStats(MBeanServerConnection serverConnectionName) {

StationsArrayListG7a = StationsArrayListG7; 

String attrName = "current";   

for(String stringName : gSelectedApplicationsFromFile) {

     try {
           String connectsName = "WowzaMediaServerPro:vHosts=VHosts,vHostName=_defaultVHost_,"
                        + "applications=Applications,applicationName=" + stringName + ",name=Connections";       

           ObjectName connectsObjName = new ObjectName(connectsName);

           try {
           Long valueObj = (Long)serverConnectionName.getAttribute(connectsObjName, attrName);

           valueX = valueObj;        
           StationsArrayListG7.add(valueX);        

       } catch (MBeanException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       } catch (AttributeNotFoundException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       } catch (InstanceNotFoundException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       } catch (ReflectionException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           System.out.println("IOException Error has occured!");
       }
       }           

       catch (MalformedObjectNameException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }  

  }  


  }
```

When I do it with individual variable instead of array it works fine. I can't figure it out if I am doing it right assigning array StationsArrayListG7a = StationsArrayListG7;. I tried copy and stuff like that but it kept giving me null.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Replacing StationsArrayListG7a = StationsArrayListG7; with StationsArrayListG7a.addAll(StationsArrayListG7); seemed to help. I'm not 100% sure yet though as I write this so I will need to do some testing. If there is anything you still know please let me know :D

UPDATE2: The method mentioned in UPDATE works. The code I use to compare is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Array1.size(); i++) {

     if (Array1.get(i) >= Array2.get(i) + difDrop) {  

}
}
```

Comment: Side note: try to avoid capitalized names for variables/properties.

Comment: Where (and how) did you declare/initialize `valueX` and `gSelectedApplicationsFromFile`?

Comment: public long valueX = 0; is set as a global variable. gSelectedApplicationsFromFile is simply a Method that reads a list of station names and returns as a array list. 

Also, I tried the answers below but they don;t seem to work. Not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating two different `ArrayList` objects:

```
List<Long> StationsArrayListG7 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Long> StationsArrayListG7a = new ArrayList<>();
```

And then you're throwing one away and assigning one to the other, meaning they now reference the same object...:

```
StationsArrayListG7a = StationsArrayListG7;
```

If you mean to copy the *contents* of one `ArrayList` to another, there is a constructor for that:

```
List<Long> StationsArrayListG7 = new ArrayList<>();
// put stuff in StationsArrayListG7
// ...
List<Long> StationsArrayListG7a = new ArrayList<>( StationsArrayListG7 );
```

Cheers,

Comment: Where do I write this code? List<Long> StationsArrayListG7a = new ArrayList<>( StationsArrayListG7 ); don't seem to do anything and it returns me empty array list [] all the time. The problem is that I need to assign the array list beforehand. The way it should work is: I assign an empty array list: StationsArrayListG7a. Fill StationsArrayListG7 with data and compare the filled one with the assigned one. First time it is empty so ignore that. After that the  StationsArrayListG7a should have values and I fill StationsArrayListG7 with new ones and compare again. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: the main thing about this code is that I want to compare each individual value so I could monitor the changes. I cannot monitor if I get both array lists same values at the same time or one empty all the time.

Comment: It is entirely not clear from your code fragments where you want to compare the two lists or even if the approach is viable at all. Also consider that the two lists might be sorted differently!

Comment: Hi Anders, All I needed to do is replace StationsArrayListG7a = StationsArrayListG7; with StationsArrayListG7a.addAll(StationsArrayListG7); and it works. Your methods doesn't work.

This code fragment is not for comparing but for getting previous and next arraylists. I am comparing with code I just updated in the top post. I would have given my full code but it is more than 1500 lines long.

Answer (score 2):

The first non-empty line in the method is assigning `StationsArrayListG7a = StationsArrayListG7;` which means that both variables now refer the same `ArrayList` object.